# Pop a largest number in a list to another list, python

Tags: python, list, max

I want to get the max() nubmer in a list and then pop it to another list, (list1).

```
x = [66,1,4,3,6,55]


list1 = []
for i in x:
    x.pop(max(x))
    #poped item saved to list1
print(list1)
```

This is my approach but i get the error " pop index out of range". What am i doing wrong ? And i really dont know how to further pop() an item and return it to an empty list.The result should be a list1 with numbers from highest to lowest. Please, dont post any other algorithm with built in functions like sort(). Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you just want to sort the array in the reverse order (from max to min), isn't it? Assuming that you have a loop in your code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide the index of the max element in a list to pop

```
x = [66,1,4,3,6,55]
list1 = [x.pop(x.index(max(x)))]
print(list1)
```

**Output**

```
[66]
```

**Request from Comments:**

```
x = [66,1,4,3,6,55]
list1 = []
while x:
    list1.append(x.pop(x.index(max(x))))
print(list1)
```

Comment: If i want to pop every single max number left in the x list to the list1, how should i do it ?

Comment: @AdamBeňko Updated solution. You can use a while loop

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it all makes sense to me :)

Comment: The code you have provided in answer is equivalent to `list1 = sorted(x,reverse=True)[:]`. Also if you just want to create a copy of list why use expensive `index` and `max` functions to get every element, when you can just simply sort the resulting list?

Answer (score 1):

In python pop method's argument is index, But you are passing values.

```
x = [66,1,4,3,6,55]
list1 = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    list1.append(x.pop(x.index(max(x))))
print(list1)
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
>>> x = [66,1,4,3,6,55]
>>> list_popped = []
>>> list_popped.append(x.pop(x.index(max(x))))
>>> print list_popped
[66]
>>> print x
[1, 4, 3, 6, 55]
```

Comment: OP is asked to add the popped item to list_1. Need little changes

Answer (score 0):

List pop method takes index of the element as argument. you are providing the item itself. In your example the first value will be 66 and you are trying pop(66), there is no item at 66th index(the length of the list is less than 66).

try the following code

```
x = [66,1,4,3,6,55]

list1 = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    max_val = max(x)
    max_val_index = x.index(max_val)
    list1.append(max_val)
    x.pop(max_val_index)
print(list1)
```

Output: [66, 55, 6, 4, 3, 1]